# Avoid the use of tailored algorithms for standard purposes. Helps in automatic parallelization

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

> Avoid the use of tailored algorithms
>   for standard purposes: For example,
>   certain applications benefit
>   marginally from complex sorting
>   algorithms tailored to the
>   characteristics of the data being
>   sorted. Replacing these with calls to
>   standard library sorting algorithms
>   can facilitate their replacement with
>   standard parallelized library calls.

Can anyone please cite an example for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author is promoting the use of already existing conveniance abstractions rather than producing highly parallelizable code for already performant operations; much in the same sense we usually are recommended to work with the `List` interface rather than `Arrays`; even though arrays can be more performant.

> Replacing these with calls to standard library sorting algorithms can facilitate their replacement with standard parallelized library calls.

So, start of with standard algorithms and classes and create your own optimizations only when a performance bottleneck is duly identified. Using standard libraries makes it easy to change the algorithms at a later point, e.g., by *subclassing*.